# Not correct explicit method is called within generics and inheritance

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-5, c#-9.0

I am trying to understand, why correct explicit implementation of my method is not called.
I have a base interface with one method and a child interface, that implements base interface and overlaps same method (with new keyword). Then, I have a class that implements only child interface and both methods are implemented explicitly.

when I create generic method with type T (where T is base interface) and call this method with child interface, the implementation of the base interface is called. I have expected, that method of given type will be called (child interface). Could you please help me to understand (or explain) why the implementation of the child interface is not called (see the output, the type is child interface)? Thanks

see code below
output from console:

IChild
Base test
Hello World!

```
interface IBase
{
    void Test();
}

interface IChild : IBase
{
    new void Test();
}

class Test : IChild
{
    void IBase.Test()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Base test");
    }

    void IChild.Test()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Child Test");
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TestMethod<IChild>(new Test());
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
    }

    static void TestMethod<T>(T test) where T : IBase
    {
        Console.WriteLine(typeof(T).Name);
        test.Test();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The first thing to understand is that `IBase.test` and `IChild.Test` are literally two different completely unrelated methods, which just happen to have the same name. In fact, if you look at the [generated IL](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghglgdgNAFxFANgHwAICYCMBYAKENgQFMAnAMwgGNSACASQCEIBnUwgb0Pr/owAWegBVSbBAAoAlAG5CAX0LEYZKrQaMAwgAtUAE3ogmrDt178YpAO4DhYiTPkElRAtlHiERproPmCfjsTdlIAOgcpaQs+HkCg/gwcAE5JACJTBjIJNLkY+ld8oV89FH0Irxl8uITElPS/Ms8cvPi+V0L3LAEcAHYAoKSANmCAWWgYSSSABgBtAF16CHIAczZotvoa2uaEUdIEHQB7fQAebVL9AD5JK1tImVadntS0gAlSFBQj+gB1I/IZQAhLlnEFOoMcCNipF9ocTqcRDcRPRsghpPRrDoKAwUcYWKFqvlIakEABPAAOpCOlEkImkYQAchAwKQnjs0RVHOz2oogA=) you'll see that one method is referenced as `IBase::Test` or `IBase.Test` and the other as `IChild::Test` or `IChild.Test` - there's literally different names used to call those two different methods.

You're constraining `TestMethod<T>` to `IBase`, so this method doesn't know about `IChild` at all. So when you call `T.Test()` the compiler generates a call to `IBase::Test()`, which completely ignores the unrelated method `IChild::Test()`.

```
    .method private hidebysig static 
        void TestMethod<(IBase) T> (
            !!T test
        ) cil managed 
    {
        // Method begins at RVA 0x2086
        // Code size 34 (0x22)
        .maxstack 8

        IL_0000: ldtoken !!T
        IL_0005: call class [System.Private.CoreLib]System.Type [System.Private.CoreLib]System.Type::GetTypeFromHandle(valuetype [System.Private.CoreLib]System.RuntimeTypeHandle)
        IL_000a: callvirt instance string [System.Private.CoreLib]System.Reflection.MemberInfo::get_Name()
        IL_000f: call void [System.Console]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
        IL_0014: ldarga.s test
        IL_0016: constrained. !!T
        IL_001c: callvirt instance void IBase::Test()
        IL_0021: ret
    } // end of method Program::TestMethod
```

Comment: Thanks for quick answer, that's what I was thinking about (constraint), I am still little bit confused why the writeline of the type T is IChild in the method (and not the IBase then, if the method does not know about IChild as you mentioned)

Comment: Because that checks the type of the type parameter at runtime, not the type of the constraint.

Comment: aa, got it thanks, do you know if the issue with constraint is somewhere documented? Thanks a lot it helped me to understand

Comment: The specification discusses how methods on constraints are called - look for `effective interface set` under this section: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/classes#type-parameter-constraints.

It's quite technical stuff. I don't know of any simpler documentation that would cover this particular case though.